# add conditional logic to controller in zend framework

Tags: zend-framework

i want to add a conditional statement to my layout that tests:

1. the controller param in the url
2. the existence of a zend_auth()

what's the best way to achieve that? i have tried testing the `$this->_getParam('controller')` in the layout but got an error. i could just set that variable in all the controllers but that seems kind of dumb.  how to best set a variable that i could use later from the layout with some conditional logic?  or should i instead add my conditional logic that is inside a view helper and then loaded into the layout?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Edit**  The controller shouldn't be a URL parameter, unless you are doing some very strange routing.  If you were getting a GET (or POST) variable, you would use `->getParam()` on the request object, `Zend_Controller_Front::getInstance()->getRequest()`, as used below.  But the controller is a separate property of that request object.

This is the auth part:

```
$loggedIn = Zend_Auth::getInstance()->hasIdentity();
```

This is the controller part:

```
$controller = Zend_Controller_Front::getInstance()->getRequest()->controller;
```

Comment: where would i use these?  in a view? controller?

Comment: They are static methods, you can use them anywhere.  I extracted this from a Zend1.11 app.  I am told that ZF2 is very different.